# Access a variable from another class in java

Tags: java, android

I have a class like this:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
     /* I removed other methods */

     public Map<String, Conversation> conversationsMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
}
```

And **Connection.java**

```
public class Connection {
/* I removed other methods */

     public class TestMessageListener implements MessageListener {  
           MainActivity mainClass;

           public void someMethod() {
                mainClass.conversationsMap.get("test"); /// This line is returning nullpointer exception
           }
     }
}
```

Why I can't access `conversationsMap` from another class ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MainActivity mainClass;` is a field of nested class `TestMessageListener` so if you will not initialize it it will be initialized with default value which for references is `null` which means that

```
mainClass.conversationsMap.get("test");
```

will try to invoke `conversationsMap.get("test")` on null, but since `null` doesn't have any fields or methods you are getting NullPointerException.

Generally to solve this kind of problem you either initialize `mainClass` yourself with new instance

```
MainActivity mainClass = new MainActivity();
```

but probably better option is to let user or other process pass already created instance to `TestMessageListener` class. To do this you can create setter,

```
public void setMainActivity(MainActivity mainClass){
    this.mainClass = mainClass;
}
```

or accept `MainActivity` in `TestMessageListener` constructor

```
public TestMessageListener(MainActivity mainClass){
    this.mainClass = mainClass;
}
```

I am not Android developer so they can be even better ways, like maybe getting this instance from some kind registered `Activity` containers but I can't help you in this case.

Comment: It fixed but this line is still giving nullpointer : ((ConversationsAdapter) mainClass.conversationsAdapter).updateConversations(mainClass.conversationsList);  do you know why ? I have a conversationsAdapter class in main class (it is public)

Comment: @Okan Sorry, was AFK. Anyway something tells me that this is same problem as in `TestMessageListener` (uninitialized field) but I can't be sure if I will not see code which will let me reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could pass the MainActivity context to the Connection constructor and then in the TestMessageListener just do something like:

```
MainActivity mainClass = (MainActivity) mContext;
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have any instance of MainActivity.

Solution is :

MainActivity mainClass = new MainActivity();

Answer (score 2):

You haven't intialized mainClass, that's why you are getting null pointer .
You can either create new Main activity(but remember that your map is not static , so any modifications that you made might be lost depending where you made them) like

```
MainActivity mainClass = new MainActivity();
```

Or Create a constructor in `Connection` class which accepts `context` and the pass Main Activity to it and later use it inside your `TestMessageListener` . E.g.

```
private MainAcitivity mainClass;
public Connection(Context context) {
mainClass = (MainAcitivity) context;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TestMessageListener implements MessageListener {
           MainActivity mainClass = new MainActivity();
     }
```

You need an instance of mainClass in order to interact with it.